# Show/hide div select multiple

Tags: jquery, select, hide, show, show-hide

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/tucuta/pvvmvdpg/

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeIn("fast")[ ($(this).val() == 'value1') ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
  $("#div2").fadeIn("fast")[ ($(this).val() == 'value2') ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
});

$("#mySelect").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="value1">First</option>
  <option value="value2">Second</option>
  <option value="value3">Third</option>
  <option value="value4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

The code works fine if it is for a normal select, but if it is for a multiple select not working.

If I select for example first shows me div 1, but if I select first and then second, it shows me neither div1 nor div2.

Someone please help me, I thank you in advance

Comment: `.val()` on multiselects returns an array. It just so happens that `["value1"] == "value1"` returns true in javascript.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt response.

I ask, as it should do, some example please ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the value you're looking for is *anywhere* in the list, via `$.inArray()`

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeIn("fast")[ $.inArray('value1', $(this).val()) >= 0 ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
  $("#div2").fadeIn("fast")[ $.inArray('value2', $(this).val()) >= 0 ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
});

$("#mySelect").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="value1">First</option>
  <option value="value2">Second</option>
  <option value="value3">Third</option>
  <option value="value4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man.

It is exactly what I was trying to do, I appreciate the help and give the issue as resolved.

Comment: @Paul Roub What about if i want to show 1st div in default when use came to the page.and then switch between the divs

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
$("#mySelect").change();
```

and it will work
because you have used the change event on '#myselect' and it will fire automatically, you dont have to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.inArray(value, array) // Return the index in array or -1 if not exists
if( $.inArray('value1', $(this).val()) != -1 ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added few lines. Its working 
[Code fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayurRahul/rkffq71s/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="value1">First</option>
  <option value="value2">Second</option>
  <option value="value3">Third</option>
  <option value="value4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<div id="div1" class="a">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="a">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="a">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="a">Div 4</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mySelect").change(function(){
        $(".a").hide();                              
        if( $(this).val()){
            for(var i=0; i < $(this).val().length; i++){
                if($(this).val()[i] == "value1"){
                        $("#div1").fadeIn("fast")['show']();
                }
                else if($(this).val()[i] == "value2"){
                        $("#div2").fadeIn("fast")['show']();
                }
                 else if($(this).val()[i] == "value3"){
                        $("#div3").fadeIn("fast")['show']();
                }
                 else if($(this).val()[i] == "value4"){
                        $("#div4").fadeIn("fast")['show']();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#mySelect").change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be this one:

**HTML**:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="value1">First</option>
  <option value="value2">Second</option>
  <option value="value3">Third</option>
  <option value="value4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<div id="div1" match="value1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" match="value2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" match="value3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4" match="value4">Div 4</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function exists(elemt,arr){
        return (jQuery.inArray(elemt,arr) > -1);
    }

    $('#mySelect').change(function(){
        var $selected = $(this).val();
        $('div').each(function(){
                $(this).fadeIn('fast')[ 
                    (exists($(this).attr('match'),$selected)) ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();      
        });
    });
});
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/stftj911/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!